# Rails - How to enable validations conditionally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, oauth, authlogic

I have a User model that looks like:

```
class User < TwitterAuth::GenericUser

 acts_as_authentic {|c|
   c.login_field = :email
   c.validate_email_field = false
   c.validate_password_field = false
  }
end
```

It uses TwitterAuth and Authlogic plugins.

I would like to selectively disable validations c.validate_email_field = false
based on whether the user is using twitter to register via normal email.

```
- With email and password registration, the validations needs to be on.
-twitter does not have email or password fields, the validation needs to be off.

 When I disable validation, the authLogic user registration using email and password fails:

 unknown attribute: password_confirmation


 I tried to selectively disable validation if attribute 'twitter_id' is present.

 c.merge_validates_confirmation_of_password_field_options({:unless => :skip_password_validation?})

def skip_password_validation
  !attribute_present?('twitter_id')
end
```

This does not work because the attribute 'twitter_id' exists in the table User whether it is used or not.

How do I selectively enable email and password validation? i,e Enable validation only if it is not using twitter oAuth.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you perhaps need to look at the other validation methods, like [validates_with](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods%3avalidates_with) that's meant for more complex validation logic. You should then be able to validate the attributes you need depending on what was passed in.

Comment: Looks like validates_with is Rails 3.0 only. I am on 2.3.5 unfortunately and that doesn't seem like an option.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. In 2.3.x I suppose you have to override the `validate` method directly. Take a look at the examples for `ActiveRecord::Validations`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving ValidationSkipper a shot:

https://github.com/npearson72/validation_skipper

Just set your validations and conditions on the User model, and skip them when you make the call to twitter.